# Is it still advisable to have a separate partition for virtual machines on Linux?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, partitioning, virtual-machine

The question might also depend on whether the virtual hard drive has a fixed size or dynamic drive size. (may dynamics get fragmented)

I have a fixed size virtual machine now for *win-xp* on a separate partition which is quite stable and fast.

But I have also an *antiX* Linux in the Vbox (on the same partition but dynamic drive size) which is somehow sluggish or jerky.

I have to set up a complete new OS on a new 500 GB drive and can not decide how to partition it.

Comment: If the partition is on the same drive as your swap and system partitions then having them on a separate partition isn't going to be any real benefit beyond being able to wipe your system partition and keep the VM data.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea if you plan to use thin provisioning on your virtual disks.  Unless you're keeping a close eye on things, there's always a chance that your virtual disks could grow to fill up the entire partition they're in.  If they're in their own partition when that happens, the rest of the (host) system won't affected.  If they aren't, then you could end up in a situation where your host has no more room to write log files (assuming you didn't also put /var/log in its own partition).

Again, this is a pretty low risk if you're managing your system well.  It's just sort of a "best practice" thing.

Comment: "...you could end up in a situation where your host has no more room to write log files" 
exactely that happend to me the very first time, I got: 'you ran out of space'